# Python - How do I make a loop to search for multiple elements in a list and store the values?

Tags: string, list, function, python-3.x, loops

Sorry for bad title, but I couldn't explain very well what I wanted to do with the title alone. I'm also new to coding. But, I'm trying to define a function that basically calculates the mass of a simple compound, the chemical formula is given as a string and you are given the number of moles. It will look like this

`chemicalMass(chemicalFormula, numMoles)`

You are also given defined variables that are lists of the elements and molar masses of the corresponding elements. The positions of both the elements and the corresponding molar mass are what should be equal to each other.

```
elements = ["H", "B", "C"]
molarMasses = [1.00794, 10.811, 12.0107]
```

H = 1.00794 , B = 10.811, etc..

```
    elements = ["H", "B", "C"]
    molarMasses = [1.00794, 10.811, 12.0107]

    def chemicalMass(chemicalFormula, numMoles)
    chemicalFormula = tuple(chemicalFormula)

print(chemicalMass('HBC', 2)
```

This is as far as I've gotten, I thought I should use `tuple` on chemical formula to break it up in single characters. But now I have no idea how to make a loop to look for each letter of the chemical formula in the "elements" list and store each position of the elements from the chemical formula in the list and match the list's positions to corresponding molar masses and add those all up to in the end multiply it with `numMoles`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary to store data like this:

```
elements = {
    'H': 1.00794,
    'B': 10.811,
    'C': 12.0107
}
```

Then your `chemicalMass` function could be something as simple as:

```
def chemicalMass(element, mass):
    return elements[element]*mass
```

Comment: I have to make use of the lists with loops is there a way to do that? I haven't learned about dictionaries or anything of that sort yet in class.